# Bitmap image not filling width

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My bitmap image refuses to fill the parent width.

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
imgView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imgView.setImageBitmap(fileBitmap);
```

But when I set `imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);` with the same image in `imgView.setImageBitmap(fileBitmap);` I get the required result.
And below is my `image_layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the trick... I had to resize the image to fit the screen width

```
//after declaring my variables
displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

if(width > fileBitmap.getWidth()) {
    int newWidth = width;
    int newHeight = width * fileBitmap.getHeight() / fileBitmap.getWidth();
    fileBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fileBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
}
```